# Move Animals Between Pens During Harvest

Tags: agricola

During the feeding stage I end up with one sheep in a pen for four and three cows, two in a pen for two and one pet.  After breeding I no longer have room for the cows.

After breeding there is no longer room for the additional cow unless I can shuffle the animals around. Is there a way to manually move them about on the iPad version of the game even if there is no swap space available on the farm?

Answer (score 3):

Usually you can drag the animals to the storage bar at the bottom of the screen to assist in moving them around.  Just like whenever you get new ones and have to drag them out, I have usually just dragged them onto that bar, near the location of their little respective icon.

Comment: That's good advice but it doesn't appear to work during harvest.

Comment: Hm.. I thought it usually did. I'll play a game and see why it's not.